# ajax code dropzone.js reloading after upload of files

Tags: javascript, ajax, dropzone

For some reason the browser reloads before uploading all files.

how can I make sure it reloads only after it completes the upload of files.

```
 $.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/Journal/SaveTransactions",
    data: transactions,
    success: function (result) {//converted result to array to get journalID and message result.Data.nameofvariable
        //alert(result.Data.message); //message called from array result

        // calls uploadfiles function from attachments controllers.


        fileDropZone.options.url = "/Blob/UploadBlob?journalID=" + result.Data.journalID;
        fileDropZone.processQueue();

        location.reload();



    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error!")

    }
});
```

Comment: You need to listen for the appropriate dropzone event https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events